# docker container not writing to mounted volume on host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I am having issue writing to the mounted volume on host filesystem from docker container

Is there some special thing i have to do when building the container to make the container write data to the mounted volume on host for persistency?

I have seen containers that write to host filesystem like the official mysql docker image and several others but when i build my own images, and i mount the volume on host, i find out it doesn't write to host, but only reads from the host.

Comment: Please add the docker command and dockerfile

Comment: You need to map volumes from host to container when start container not in dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

I think for certain docker images, one need to give access to the host mounted volume to same ui/gid of running container to host as well for write to work properly

Comment: Yep, you can see how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67021906/1178971)